# Transcribe a csv column in awk, accounting for empty fields

Tags: text-processing, awk

Let's say I have a csv file with several columns. `NF` is not constant. At the moment, to replace columns > 4 with lowercase, I'm doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
#call with `awk -f lowercase.awk in.csv > out.csv`
BEGIN {
    OFS=",";
    FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")";
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        if(i>4 && $i){
            $i = tolower($i);
        }
    }
    print $0;
}
```

But this doesn't take into account adjacent field separators (empty columns denoted by repeated commas) in the csv file like `,,,,`. How can I take these into account? I don't like [the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969984/awk-coping-when-column-is-occassionly-empty) because they don't generalise well (there's a lot of conditional checking, and my real-world application of this has `NF` > 40 and < 70).

Unit test:

in.csv

```
apple,orange,banana,cherry,MELON,"Fruit salad",grape
"Lots of vegtables",CUCUMBER,carrot,potato,RADISH,BeetrOOT
Bread,BAGEL,,,,Croissant
```

out.csv

```
apple,orange,banana,cherry,melon,"fruit salad",grape
"Lots of vegtables",CUCUMBER,carrot,potato,radish,beetroot
Bread,BAGEL,,,,croissant
```

Comment: Would you like to put a `print NF` before the `for(i=1...` line? It would give you a clue if the problem is the FPAT expression.

Comment: I have done that. NF varies, but will still vary even if I account for `/[,*]/` because each line is not necessarily the same length at the end (i.e. the number of fields per record varies in the in.csv)

Comment: I know it varies, but does it match with the number of fields? I believe *awk* is splitting by `space character` only and is ignoring FPAT.

Comment: Keep in mind that **FPAT** was added in GNU awk 4.0. So previous versions will ignore it.

Comment: `NF` seems to be indicating that FPAT is interpreted correctly. I'm using gawk 4.0.1.

Comment: Then FPAT should be `"([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy done by `sed`

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1\L\3/' file.csv
```

if you don't like escaping characters you can modify script (for GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(([^,]*,){4})(.*)/\1\L\3/' file.csv
```

which find four groups of any(0 included) non-comma symbols followed by comma and leave it unchanged (`\1`) and exchange all in remaining part of the string (`\3`) to lower version.
Or by `cut` and `paste`

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f-4 file.csv) <(cut -d, -f5- file.csv | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')
```

Comment: Thanks, I follow the `cut` and `paste` solution. Could you explain the `sed` regex? I'm having trouble deciphering why so many escaped `()` and `{}` and I can't understand the interpretation at https://regex101.com/

Comment: I think your solution doesn't generalise beyond the unit test. `(([^,]){4})(.*)` only works for the string `,,,,`, not a variable number of commas.

Comment: @Escher Do not change my regex  as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood something about the question, so please pardon me if I have.  It seems, though, that you should be able to simply `tolower` any field greater than 4 (or 40, or whatever you choose).  For example:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
   }
{
    for (i = 4 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
        $i = tolower($i)
        }
    $1 = $1
    print
}
```

After all, `tolower(*some empty field*)` is simply an empty field.  Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Edit:  My output:

```
apple,orange,banana,cherry,melon,"fruit salad",grape
"Lots of vegtables",CUCUMBER,carrot,potato,radish,beetroot
Bread,BAGEL,,,,croissant
```

Comment: Run it on the unit test and you'll see that it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: In fact, it does.  I even did md5sums on your posted `out.csv` and my output.  Both were `b0d60727ff4eaefee6b986bf5c64777d`.  It is char-for-char identical to what was posted as correct output.

Comment: OK, odd. I copied your exact script into a file `test.awk`, ran it with `awk -f test.awk < in.csv` and got different output (capital 'C' on "croissant" for example. The output of `awk -f test.awk < in.csv | md5sum
` is 443650f9c61a467fd59c5298fc655f31. I did that in gawk 4.1.1. What are you using?

Comment: Just looked closely at your code, and couldn't see anything wrong, so I fiddled a little and figured out that gawk requires `FS=','`. Then it produces the same output. Thanks for the anwer!

Comment: Vote ups are appreciated :-)